# Eclipse for C/C++: Jvm terminated error

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu-16.04

I installed over Ubuntu GNU/Linux 16.04.2 VM the latest eclipse IDE for C/C++ via the eclipse oxygen provided via http://www.eclipse.org/.

After a complete Installation when I try to run the eclipse Application I get the following error:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-jar /home/user/eclipse/cpp-oxygen/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /home/user/eclipse/cpp-oxygen/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/user/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.550.v20170928-1359/eclipse_1629.so
-startup /home/user/eclipse/cpp-oxygen/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 3d800b
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
-vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-jar /home/user/eclipse/cpp-oxygen/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
```

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I don't see an error. All it says is JVM Exited with code 1. Is there an error ? are there logs ? is that all the output ?

Comment: Yeap the exlise just opened a windows with all this long message.

Comment: Try `sudo update-alternatives --config java`

Comment: According to this link I found: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/226135/  It seems like you may have to install the "official" jdk rather than the openjdk you have installed. (Seems wrong to me, since ubuntu should have the right dependencies, but I'm fairly clueless).

Answer (score -1):

I had this same problem and have just managed to fix it.

The error message is saying that it is looking for Java version 1.8, but it can only find version 1.9.

First make sure you have java 1.8 installed.
If you open a terminal and enter the command RustyX suggested:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

you will be shown a lists of java versions on your machine and asked to select a version to be your default. Pick 1.8 and try opening eclipse again, it should work now.